# tcp_nodelay setting for unix domain socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, tcp

I am trying to set flag tcp_nodelay on a unix domain socket. Can we set it or does it even make sense to set tcp_nodelay for UNIX domain sockets, specifically on Linux?

please advise.

thanks

Comment: Does not make sense. Unix domain sockets don't use TCP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unix domain sockets don't use Nagle (and obviously don't use TCP either). Also, the fact that it's called `tcp_nodelay` indicates it's a TCP-only thing.